# Run Entrypoint and CMD on file change docker-compose

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to run my container and mount directories. 
Docker container runs fine but i need to build the distribution of my code on every update so that developers can test it out in their local machines.
Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-coontainer:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    container_name: my-coontainer
    hostname: my-coontainer
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/src/my-coontainer:delegated
      - ~/.npm:/opt/src/my-coontainer/.npm
    restart: unless-stopped
    entrypoint: ["/opt/src/my-coontainer/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    external:
      name: my-network
```

My entrypoint is a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Build project 
yarn build

# Parsing nginx conf
j2 nginx/default.conf.j2 > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

exec "$@"
```

I tried it running it works fine but when i change something on my host machine change gets reflected in file inside container but the `yarn build` process does not fire again neither the Nginx is restarted

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you give to your colleagues?  Can they `docker run` a built image in a repository, or do they also need a complete copy of the application source tree on their local systems?

Comment: `yarn build process does not fire again neither the Nginx is restarted` you need to do it manually. Or implement some method outside your container that will monitor for changes. Once the container is build, it is build, you build another container, you need to download that another container and run it. There is no "online" change unless  you implement it.

Comment: what i heard online is that if you mount directories docker will be able to trigger any file update and recopmpile the container